# Android Volley request throwing Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, php, android, android-volley

I have been using Android `Volley` library to perform requests to PHP scripts in my server for quite some time. Now I am getting an unusual error when I do that.

My Android code to call the script is as follows:

```
 private void writeDatatoDB(){

    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL , new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String,String> maps = new HashMap<>();
            maps.put(SinchHolders.phpUserName,uName);
            maps.put(SinchHolders.phpUserNickName,uNick);
            maps.put(SinchHolders.phpUserPassword,uPass);
            maps.put(SinchHolders.phpUserFirebaseToken,uFCM);
            maps.put(SinchHolders.phpUserProfession,uUserProf);
            maps.put(SinchHolders.phpUserexpertise,uUserExp);
            maps.put(SinchHolders.phpUserGender,ugender);
            maps.put(SinchHolders.phpUserZip,uZip);
            maps.put(SinchHolders.phpUserBirthYear,uBirth);
            return maps;

        }
    };
    RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(dummy_signup_2.this);
    rq.add(sr);
}
```

The PHP script that the `Volley` library is as follows:

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ){
        $id = $_POST['UserName'];
        $nick =$_POST['NickName'];
        $pass =$_POST['UserPassword'];
        $FirebaseToken = $_POST['FireBaseId'];
        $BDate = $_POST['bithdate'];
        $ZCode = $_POST['zipcode'];
        $Gender = $_POST['sex'];
        $UserProfession = $_POST['userprofession'];
        $userexpert = $_POST['userexpertise'];
        $sql="insert into `User`(`UserNickName`, `UserName`, `password`, `createDate`, `FirebaseToken`, `BirthYear`, `ZipCode`, `Gender`, `UserProfession`, `UserExpertise`) values ('$nick','$id','$pass',Default,'$FirebaseToken','$BDate','$ZCode','$Gender','$UserProfession','$UserExpertise')";
        require_once('db_connect_me.php');
        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
            echo"Success";
        }
        else{
            echo "Failure";
        }
        mysqli_close($con);
    }else{
        echo "Error";
    }
    ?>
```

The error that the `Volley` is throwing me is `com.android.volley.VolleyError: Java.Lang.NullPointerException`. The error is caused by some error from the server side, because the error is diaplayed in the toast that has been defined in the `ErrorListener`. I do not understand what the problem could possibly be. I have created a simple helloworld php file and called that using the same code and I was able to get the output. What could possibly be wrong with this?

StackTrace :

```
01-27 19:11:41.715 12548-16431/com.example.****.****E/Volley: [2720] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                             at libcore.net.UriCodec.encode(UriCodec.java:132)
                                                                             at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:57)
                                                                             at com.android.volley.Request.encodeParameters(Request.java:450)
                                                                             at com.android.volley.Request.getBody(Request.java:436)
                                                                             at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:260)
                                                                             at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:234)
                                                                             at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:107)
                                                                             at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
                                                                             at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
```

PS : Please read the question carefully and you would understand that this is not a duplicate any `NullPointerException` questions found in this website.

Comment: Which line is throwing the *NullPointerException*?

Comment: @adalPaRi The response from the script is throwing the exception. The toast that is given in the `ErrorListener ` is throwing that exception.

Comment: you php code my lead to SQL injection, please use mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: @Anton Yes I will change that, but I don't that could be the cause of the error?

Comment: kindly post your stacktrace

Comment: @Tyson then *VolleyError* is *null*. You should check what response you are getting from server. I mean, what Volley is directly getting.

Comment: @adalPari Volley would be getting the echo statements from the PHP code as the response. That is how my previous PHP codes that were very much similar to this have worked.

Comment: Try to change `error.toString()` to `error.getMessage()` (maybe `error.getMessage().toString()` ) but i am not sure..try both.

Comment: your params has something null string.

Comment: @W4R10CK I don't think that would be the case, I am retrieving all my params using `SharedPreferences` . So even if the value is not found then the default value (which also a string) would be taken by the param.

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos I tried `error.getMessage()`, Now it is only showing `Java.Lang.NullPointerException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will get this `exception`, when the any of the `params` value is null. Check your value parameters in `params`

```
 @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        //put your map keys
        return checkParams(params);
    }

 private Map<String, String> checkParams(Map<String, String> map){               
        Iterator<Entry<String, String>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, String> pairs = (Map.Entry<String, String>)it.next();
            if(pairs.getValue()==null){
                map.put(pairs.getKey(), "");
            }
        }
        return map;             
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `NullPointException` is caused by one value which you tying to put into DB and does not get value from user. Missing - `createDate`:

Params into DB are 10:

```
`UserNickName`, `UserName`, `password`, `createDate`, `FirebaseToken`, `BirthYear`, `ZipCode`, `Gender`, `UserProfession`, `UserExpertise`
```

you missed the input Value for:

```
`createDate`
```

From user only 9:

```
maps.put(SinchHolders.phpUserName,uName);
maps.put(SinchHolders.phpUserNickName,uNick);
maps.put(SinchHolders.phpUserPassword,uPass);
maps.put(SinchHolders.phpUserFirebaseToken,uFCM);
maps.put(SinchHolders.phpUserProfession,uUserProf);
maps.put(SinchHolders.phpUserexpertise,uUserExp);
maps.put(SinchHolders.phpUserGender,ugender);
maps.put(SinchHolders.phpUserZip,uZip);
maps.put(SinchHolders.phpUserBirthYear,uBirth);
```

Comment: The createDate is given the default value which would be the `SERVER_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: But there is an option by which you can make the default as Timestamp and it is working perfectly when I execute the query from the SQL query box in PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Also I think you are correct with the suggestion that null is being sent as one of the params. I hardcoded all the values and now I am able to send a successful request and the data is being entered into the DB. I am checking all the values one by one to determine which of them is null